# Xenforo 1.4.5 Icon Error

Tags: css, xenforo

I am trying to assign some of the new 4.3 icons to my forum nodes.
Here is the forum link: [enter link description here](http://forum.partyserver.us/)

The problem I am having is the older icons show up just fine, but the new icons show up as a square white box.
Here is some existing working code followed by the new icon code that is not working.

Working Icon:

```
/* General Chat */
.node_9 .forumNodeInfo .nodeIcon:before {content: '\f1d7' !important;}
```

Not Working Icon:

```
/* Requests */
.node_112 .forumNodeInfo .nodeIcon:before {content: '\f234' !important;}
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

I did read this:

> EASY: Default CSS
>
> Use this method to get the default Font Awesome CSS.
>
> Copy the entire font-awesome directory into your project. In the
>    of your html, reference the location to your
>   font-awesome.min.css.  Check out the
>   examples to start using Font Awesome!

I do not understand what it is asking me where to do, as all of my customization are in extra.css . I do not have a RAW html site that uses

Thank You

Comment: Where is the `Requests` forum?

Comment: Try again, just enabled viewable for unreg users.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old CDN reference URL for FontAwesome.

Replace in header

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

with this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```